# How to get refresh token using buildinglink web api

Tags: api

I am not able to get refresh token using below process

```
Method: POST
Request URL: https://auth.buildinglink.com/connect/token
Params:
username:xxxxxx
password:xxxxxx
grant_type:password
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

How can I refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

you missed client_id

get new token

https://auth.buildinglink.com/connect/token?grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&client_id=CLIENT_ID

if you need refresh token

https://auth.buildinglink.com/connect/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have also tried with client_id but still getting same error- invalid_client

Comment: I am facing same issue in my building-link web api while passing grant_type is password with parameter(username, password, grant_type, client_id)